# PHP choose another username

Tags: php, sql, database

I have made a registration PHP file that runs through an authentication and connects to my database that I made in phpMyAdmin. The problem is, I can put in the same username without consequence and it adds to the database, so I could put; dogs as the username and then again put the same. 
How can I make it so the user is told; that username already exists choose another one.
Here's my php so far;
Also please tell me where to insert it.

```html
<?php
require('db.php');
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $email    = stripslashes($email);
    $email    = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $query    = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, trn_date) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$trn_date')";
    $result   = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result) {
        echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
} else {
?>
```

Comment: Query the database to see if there are any results where username = $username?  Don't understand why you are asking really.

Comment: Either make the username field in the DB `unique` or query the DB to check if the username already exists.

Comment: I would take Pedro's advice on the unique username field in the DB. If you have issues with DB halts, you could possibly register the same username twice due to concurrency issues (rare case but possible).

Answer (score 1):

You should query the database before inserting any record (user) to `users` table.
Try the code below:

```
<?php
$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $username ); //Sql injection prevention
$existance = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");
if( !$existance ){
    $query    = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, trn_date) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$trn_date')";
    $result   = mysql_query( $query );
    if ( $result ) {
        echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
    else{
        //unsuccessful insertion
    }
} else {
    //the user existed already, choose another username
}
?>
```

Comment: I put in the code as you instructed into the registration.php page and I was still able to put in the same username and log in. I'm unsure if I put it in the right spot honestly.

Answer (score 0):

Create an if-statement where you check if `$username` exists in the db. If it does, throw an error. If not, continue with the code.

**Note**

Your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection. Read this post: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting my entire answer to a working example. I'm going to assume your post variables are the same as mine: email, password, username

```
<?php
$errorMessage = "";



function quote_smart($value, $handle) {

   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $value = stripslashes($value);
   }

   if (!is_numeric($value)) {
       $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
   }
   return $value;
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = $_POST['username'];


        $email1 = $_POST['email'];
        $username1 = $_POST['username'];
        $password1 = $_POST['password'];

$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
$username = htmlspecialchars($username);

        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","DBuser", "DBpassword");
    if (!$connect) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("DBName");
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
            $kudots = $row['username']; }
            if ($kudots != ""){
                $errorMessage = "Username Already Taken";
                $doNothing = 1;
            }
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
            $kudots2 = $row2['email']; }
            if ($kudots2 != ""){
                $errorMessage = "Email Already in use";
                $doNothing = 1;
            }

//test to see if $errorMessage is blank
//if it is, then we can go ahead with the rest of the code
//if it's not, we can display the error

    if ($errorMessage == "") {

    $user_name = "DBUsername";
    $pass_word = "DBPassword";
    $database = "DBName";
    $server = "localhost";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

        $email = quote_smart($email, $db_handle);
        $password = quote_smart($password, $db_handle);
        $username = quote_smart($username, $db_handle);


        if ($username1 == ""){
            $errorMessage = "You need a username";
        }
        if ($password1 == ""){
            $errorMessage = $errorMessage . "<br>You need a password.";
        }
        if (!(isset($_POST['email']))){
            $errorMessage = $errorMessage . "<br>You need an email.";
        }
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $email";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            $errorMessage = "email already exists";
            $doNothing = 1;
        }


        if ($errorMessage == "") {

            $SQL = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES ($email, $username, $password)";

            $result = mysql_query($SQL);

            mysql_close($db_handle);

        //=================================================================================
        //  START THE SESSION AND PUT SOMETHING INTO THE SESSION VARIABLE CALLED login
        //  SEND USER TO A DIFFERENT PAGE AFTER SIGN UP
        //=================================================================================
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['email'] = "$email1";
                $_SESSION['password'] = "$password1";

                header ("Location: myaccount.php");

    else {
        $errorMessage = "Database Not Found";
    }

}
```

OK, now echo $errorMessage right below or above the form, to inform the user that the Email, or Username is taken. I'm pretty sure I have a duplicate function in here for the Email, but this code does work; disregard if somebody says it's vulnerable to SQL injection; this is a working EXAMPLE! If you want to do MySQL real escape string, just Google it. I had to rewrite a couple things because I don't want my full code on a public board, if for some odd reason this doesn't work; send me an eMail(canadezo121@gmail.com) and I'll send you the full page code. (Which WORKS!) This code will probably raise some concerns with other more professional coders, this example gives you a good logical viewpoint of what goes on and how it works. You can adjust it to MySQLi, PDO, etc as you get more familiar with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Where would I insert this inside of the code? Would I make another else statement?

Comment: I updated my answer. Read it and adjust as you need it so it suits your needs. Please give my answer a +1 if it helped you. It helps build my reputation.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. That's the error im getting, where should I put this snippet of code in my register.php code?

Comment: Sorry that happened to me too when I get home I'll submit a full working example. I just worked on a project that's doing the exact thing you're asking.

Comment: Thank you so much Jimmy, I cant wait to see it!

Comment: OK, I changed my entire answer to a working example. I rewrote a couple things to keep my site project safe. I just didn't want my code on a public board. If for some reason it don't work, email me and I'll send you the full code. canadezo121@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

1 you must verify if the username all ready exists in database (Select)

2 if not exists after you can insert the new user